# Можно ли пропустить изучение процедурного стиля и изучать ООП?

Tags: php

После изучения основ php нужно ли практиковаться в написании скриптов (регистрация, отправка писем и т. п.) в процедурном стиле?

Или можно сразу переходить к изучению и практике ООП?

Спасибо!

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ..... У меня вот на сайте визитке отправка почты происходит простым скриптом, без всяких ООП. Небольшой автоответчик написан скриптом, не через ООП, небольшой скан некоторого АПИ написан скриптом в 100 строк, а не ООП, при этом проекты чаще на ООП, т.к. уже стандарт..... Так что всё зависит от ситуации...... Но, наверное, главное знать основы языка, тогда и то и то примерно одинаково. Прощупать простые функции и написать что-то простое (не форму регистрации, а что-то требующее чистой  логики) - вот это можно потренить без ооп